# Setting up Dependency Injection using StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

Currently I am trying to set up Dependency Injection using StructureMap for my MVC 5 project.

Following the instructions to set up the design pattern, it continues to fail in the regard when I try and make a call to the controller using the Route Prefix the constructors are never hit, so the object is never initialized, so the program keeps stating the object needs initializing. Prior to this issue, the program would not compile without parameterless constructors but when I do add a parameterless constructor the Interface object I use in the controller is null.

I am following the naming convention that is required by the framework, so the objects should be picked up by the default methods provided by StructureMap, and that is initialized in the **DefaultRegistry.cs** which is prebuilt when you install StructerMap in the Nuget Packages.

The format for the classes that are using the Repository Design Pattern are below:

**Controller Class:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/data")]
public class TrialController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITeacherService _teacherService;

    public TrialController(ITeacherService teacherService)
    {
        _teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    [Route("trial")]
    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        _teacherService.GetTeacher();
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public interface ITeacherService
{
    void GetTeacher();
}

public class TeacherService : ITeacherService
{
    public ITeacherRepository _teacherRepository;

    public TeacherService(ITeacherRepository teacherRepository)
    {
        _teacherRepository = teacherRepository;
    }

    public void GetTeacher()
    {
        _teacherRepository.GetTeacher();
    }
}
```

**Repository Class**

```
public interface ITeacherRepository
{
    bool GetTeacher();
}

public class TeacherRepository : ITeacherRepository
{
    public readonly ITeacherRepository _teacherRepository;

    public TeacherRepository(ITeacherRepository teacherRepository)
    {
        _teacherRepository = teacherRepository;
    }

    public bool GetTeacher()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking your time to read this, and if any advice on how to resolve issue much appreciated :)

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Why does your teacher repository both inherit and take a `ITeacherRepository` into the constructor?

Comment: That is a mistake regarding the initializing of the repository in the constructor, as it is redundant. I have updated the question, if it still does not met the Minimal, Complete and Viable to you guys, I'll take it down again and try and post it better. I don't want to be a pain and waste peoples time :)

Comment: `the program would not compile without parameterless constructors but when I do add a parameterless constructor` - There is your problem. The error message doesn't mean you should add a parameterless constructor when using DI, it means you need to configure the `IControllerFactory` or `IDependencyResolver` in MVC to resolve instances through your DI container.